# linux mtp permit only read file

Tags: fedora, dolphin, mtp

In Fedora 24 with KDE and Dolphin i see my old phone Samsung U700 but I can not add new file

> Unable to create directory /SGH-U700/Card/filesystem/New_Folder.

Answer (score 0):

Install the required packages : `gvfs-mtp` and [`simple-mtpfs`](https://github.com/phatina/simple-mtpfs):

```
sudo dnf install gvfs-mtp simple-mtpfs
```

Activate the MTP mode on your Phone then mount it through:

```
simple-mtpfs ~/mnt
```